# I'm trying to calculate the difference between two times (HH:MM:SS) in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nsdateformatter

I have two `UIButtons` that mark the time in two different `UITextFields`.
I have a `UIButton` to calculate on the action to determine the difference.

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var timeatf1TextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var timeatf2TextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var timediffTextField: UITextField!

@IBAction func markf1Button(_ sender: Any) {
    let now = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    formatter.dateFormat = "HH:MM:SS"
    let dateString = formatter.string(from: now)
    timeatf1TextField.text = dateString
}

@IBAction func markf2Button(_ sender: Any) {
    let now = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    formatter.dateFormat = "HH:MM:SS"
    let dateString = formatter.string(from: now)
    timeatf2TextField.text = dateString
}
    timediffTextField.text = "\((Double(timeatf2TextField.text ??     
    "0.0") ?? 0.0) - (Double(timeatf1TextField.text ?? "0.0") ?? 0.0))"
```

The result I get on the `timediffTextField.text` action is 0.0.
I appreciate any help here!

Comment: `HH:mm:ss` is the correct format. `MM` is month. `SS` is fractional seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timeatf1TextField` and `timeatf2TextField` don't contain doubles, they contain `String`s representing the formatted time.

I would, instead, have two properties, which were types of `Date` which mark the start and times.  When the appropriate `markXxx` function is called, you would set the `Date` to the appropriate property (like you are doing, but to a property rather then local variable)

This will mean you don't need to parse the `String` values back to a `Date` value

Then I'd use `Date#timeIntervalSince(Date)` to calculate the difference between these values

Also, the date format you probably want to be using is `HH:mm:ss` (`MM` is month)

```
@IBOutlet weak var timeatf1TextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var timeatf2TextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var timediffTextField: UITextField!

var dateFormat: DateFormater = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
}()

// Yes, this could be an array
var mark1: Date?
var mark2: Date?

@IBAction func markf1Button(_ sender: Any) {
    mark1 = Date()
    let dateString = dateFormat.string(from: mark1 ?? Date())
    timeatf1TextField.text = dateString
}

@IBAction func markf2Button(_ sender: Any) {
    mark2 = Date()
    let dateString = dateFormat.string(from: mark2 ?? Date())
    timeatf2TextField.text = dateString
}
```

Then when required...

```
guard let mark1 = mark1, let mark2 = mark2 else {
    return
}
let time: TimeInterval = mark2.timeIntervalSince(mark1)
```

You could use something like [`DateComponentsFormatter`](https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/topics/78-dates) to format the resulting duration into something human readable

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give this a shot.